# Laravel - How to get user id in app service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to get user id in my app service provider, but I get an error show that ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object, any idea how on how to get user id?

AppServiceProvider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Project;

use Log;
use Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    { 
        $userid =  Auth::user()->id;
        Log::info('userid :', [$userid]);


        $project = Project::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();

    }
}
```

Error:

```
local.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\test\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp64\www\test\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php(20): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\f...', 20, Array) #1 [internal function]: App\Providers\AppServiceProvider->boot() #2 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(734): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array) #4 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(717): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider)) #5 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider), 19) #6 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(718): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure)) #7 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot() #8 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application)) #9 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(222): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array) #10 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(117): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap() #11 C:\wamp64\www\test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(87): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #12 C:\wamp64
```

Comment: I mean, what if the user isn't authenticated? You can't access `->id` if they're not logged in. You also can't access it from the command line if you run any artisan commands. It also seems like you want to provide a global application variable. If that's the case, a view composer might be better for you, if that's what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I only check this after they login. But still can't get the id. @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Is your query returning array or object? If you dump it out, you might find that it's an array and all you need is an array access ([]) instead of an object access (->).

Comment: Try the namespace `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` instead of `Auth`. Or I think there's a helper method so you can do `auth()->user()->id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `View::composer('*',)`  to use Auth in all view .

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
.........
public function boot()
{ 
     View::composer('*', function($view)
     {
         if (Auth::check()){
         $project = Project::where('user_id',Auth::id() )->count();
    }
 });
```

You can understand it as after authentication  before view render you need to check between these not before.

Answer (score 0):

Auth will always try to get the id even user is logged in or not. In case user is not logged in then it will give you non-object error because nothing is there to get via User  model object.

```
 public function boot()
    { 
        if (Auth::check()) {
           $userid =  Auth::user()->id;
           Log::info('userid :', [$userid]);


           $project = Project::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->count();
        }

    }
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the `boot()` method of your service providers, you should only bootstrap your application and not perform any action regarding looking up or outputting data. You can do this in the `register()` method of your providers, if it is really necessary to do it in a service provider. A better place would probably be a controller or a command anyway, though.

---

Using `Auth::user()` directly is dangerous as well, because there might be no user authenticated in your app. You can instead perform a `if(Auth::check()) { ... }` before accessing the user with `Auth::user()`, or, which in your case would be sufficient, you can access the user id with `Auth::id()`. It will also return `null` if no user is available, i.e. `Auth::check() === false`.